# Asp.net JQuery Plugin Confirm Box not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to display a confirm dialog box on my asp.net website before the user upload the data.

I am using http://marcosesperon.es/apps/messi/ plugin for dialog box.

The dialog box appears on client click.

I want the server side code to be executed only when the user click Yes.

I am able to display the confirm box but my server side code is not executed.

Please help.

Client Code

```
var confirmed = false;

if (!confirmed) {
    new Messi('Do you want to update status ?.', {
        title: 'Confirm',
        buttons: [{ id: 0, label: 'Yes', val: 'Y' }, { id: 1, label: 'No', val: 'N' }],
        callback: function (val) {
           confirmed=val;
        }
    }
    );
}

return confirmed;
```

This is my code.

Server Code

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" CssClass="myButton2" runat="server" OnClientClick="if( ! Button2Confirm()) return false;" Text="Update" Width="117px" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a jQuery Ajax call for this situation.

Please see this below example of a sample jQuery Ajax call

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

```
var confirmed = false;

 if (!confirmed) {
new Messi('Do you want to update status ?.', {
    title: 'Confirm',
    buttons: [{ id: 0, label: 'Yes', val: 'Y' }, { id: 1, label: 'No', val: 'N' }],
    callback: function (val) {
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Your_webpage.aspx/your_web_method",
      data: '{name: confirmed }',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: OnSuccess,
      failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
         }
      });
     }
    }
   );
 }

 return confirmed;
```

:)

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: I am using the plugin for alert box on other pages using the same plugin. I want the look of the website to be standard. Plus I want to know whats wrong in this code rather than an altenate solution

Comment: If you are not interested to use the Ajax call then you try to rectify the difference between both pages.

Comment: Please check any syntax error occurred in your jQuery.

Comment: I have never used a JQuery Ajax call. I tried

var confirmed = false;

if (!confirmed) {
new Messi('Do you want to update status ?.', {
title: 'Confirm',
buttons: [{ id: 0, label: 'Yes', val: 'Y' }, { id: 1, label: 'No', val: 'N' }],
callback: function (val) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "OperationJob.aspx/Button2_Click",
data: '{name: confirmed }',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: OnSuccess,
failure: function (response) {
alert(response.d);
}
});
}
}
);
}
return confirmed;
   
But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
return confirmed;
```

is run before the button callback so this function will always return false. You must call your server side code in the callback function:

```
new Messi('Do you want to update status ?.', {
    title: 'Confirm',
    buttons: [{ id: 0, label: 'Yes', val: 'Y' }, { id: 1, label: 'No', val: 'N' }],
    callback: function (val) {
       if(val == 'Y')
          // call server side
    }
}
);
```

To call your button click you could use things like:

```
__doPostBack('Button2','');
```

in JavaScript but I suggest you take a look at [jQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

If you want to do it in OnClientClick you can't use your plugin and must go back to JavaScript confirm funcion:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm("Are you sure?");"
```

confirm will halt execution until user presses one of the buttons.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to call server side code

Comment: I tried

                     callback: function (val) {
                        if (val == 'Y') {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            return false;
                        }
                        }
      
But It didn't work :(

Comment: That wont work either because return confirmed; will return false before you even get there.